# Wordpress Gravity Forms: Pass dropdown's value to 2nd page's dropdown

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Wordpress Gravity Form.

On the 1st page of the form, I have a dropdown box that is dynamically populated. No problems here.

Now, on the 2nd page of the **same form**, I have another dropdown that I need to dynamically populate too, based on the selected option from the 1st dropdown.

Is this possible, and if so, would not be too complicated to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where I'm populating a drop down on page 2 with post meta based on the post selected from a drop down on page 1:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_918', 'populate_post_meta' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_918', 'populate_post_meta' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_918', 'populate_post_meta' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_918', 'populate_post_meta' );
function populate_post_meta( $form ) {

    $field_id      = 3;
    $post_field_id = 1;

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->id != $field_id ) {
            continue;
        }

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
        // more info: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
        $post_id   = rgpost( "input_{$post_field_id}" );
        $post_meta = get_post_custom( $post_id );

        $choices = array();

        foreach ( $post_meta as $value ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $value[0], 'value' => $value[0] );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select a Value';
        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Full code here: http://pastie.org/private/okftjhfkmzgqkwhneixmg

Comment: I've been searching for documentation on that rgpost() for days but can't find any!

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/cbixd6wtmaeounwailqq —
Those two lines are equivalent with one exception. If you attempt to retrieve a $_POST property that does not exist, it will throw a warning. rgpost() is just a helper function that returns the property form the $_POST but only if it is set. Otherwise, it will return an empty string.